# How do i filter different database with one search box?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

This is the code I am using. When I enter a keyword in my textbox, my both datagridview displays the data source from datagridview1

```
 Private Sub txt_search_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_search.TextChanged
        Try
            Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
            DV.RowFilter = String.Format("FullName Like '%{0}%'", txt_search.Text)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
            DataGridView2.DataSource = DV
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: You may need to rebind the DataGridViews with calls to `DataBind()`

Comment: Is there more than one DataTable in the DataSet? Are the DataGridView `.DataMember` properties set to anything?

Comment: Of course they show the same thing, you bound them to the same DataSource.  No need to create a DataView, use `dbDataSet.Tables(X).DefaultView.RowFilter` to set individual filters (where X is the table index or name for each table)

Comment: oh, the name tricked me :] `DataView` doesn't have constructor that accepts `DataSet`

Answer (score 0):

Don't create new `DataViews` each time.  If you have bound `DataViews` in the first place then set the `RowFilter` of those existing `DataViews` rather than creating new ones.  If you have bound `DataTables` then set the `RowFilter` of the `DefaultView` of each of those `DataTables`.

If you want to do it right though, add a `BindingSource` to your form for each `DataGridView`.  You would then bind your `DataTables` to those `BindingSources` and then bind them to the grids.  You would then set the `Filter` property of each `BindingSource`.